# Terraform local provisioner adds '$'\r to filenames

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform to create pem files.

This is my code:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "create_key" {
   algorithm     = "RSA"
   rsa_bits      = 4096

   provisioner "local-exec" {
     interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
     command   = <<-EOT
        mkdir keypairs
        cd keypairs
        echo "${tls_private_key.create_key.private_key_pem}"     > "${var.deployment_name}.pem"
        echo "${tls_private_key.create_key.public_key_openssh}"  > "${var.deployment_name}.pem.pub"
    EOT
  }
}
```

However, this seems to add `'$'\r` at both the directory name and the file names.
For example, resulting directory would be named: `keypairs'$'\r` 
I am using Terraform with VS Code, running on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL.

Any idea how I can get around this?

Read different sources, tried various things but not found a solution.

Comment: Which line endings are you using in VSCode, CRLF or LF?

Comment: Just tested it now, it is as i suspected and as Marko said, a CRLF / LF issue. 
Your .tf is in CRLF, switch it to LF (select the .tf and bottom-right you will see CRLF, click on it to change to LF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `<<-EOT` ... `EOT` section of this configuration Terraform will take the line endings of those lines exactly as they are in your file.

It seems like you've saved this file with Windows-style line endings (CRLF) and so the effective result of that template also has Windows-style line endings. `bash` seems to be unable to support Windows-style line endings and so the CR part is being interpreted as part of the command line, rather than as part of the line separator.

If you save this `.tf` file with Unix-style line endings instead (just LF) then those line endings will be included in the result of rendering the template, which I expect will achieve the result you wanted.

---

[Provisioners are a last resort](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort), so here's a different way to get that result using resources:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    tls = {
      source = "hashicorp/tls"
    }
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
    }
  }
}

resource "tls_private_key" "create_key" {
  algorithm     = "RSA"
  rsa_bits      = 4096
}

resource "local_file" "private_key" {
  filename          = "${var.deployment_name}.pem"
  sensitive_content = tls_private_key.create_key.private_key_pem
}

resource "local_file" "public_key" {
  filename = "${var.deployment_name}.pem.pub"
  content  = tls_private_key.create_key.public_key_openssh
}
```